# Redirect to HTTPS except localhost

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I have asp.net core 2.2.1 app hosted in IIS.

How do I enforce HTTPS except when the request if from/to localhost.

Comment: You want to enforce HTTPS only in production? Or when would the request be coming from localhost?

Comment: No, in production, when I log in to the server I want to test the page on local host without https

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For condition for `UseHttpsRedirection`, you could try `MapWhen` like below:

```
app.MapWhen(context =>
{
    var url = context.Request.Path.Value;
    return url.Contains("localhost") && !context.Request.IsHttps;
}, subapp =>
{
    subapp.UseHttpsRedirection();
});
```

Comment: This could work, but I would use better check for localhost, e.g.: https://www.strathweb.com/2016/04/request-islocal-in-asp-net-core/.

url can contain localhost anywhere in path, e.g. www.somesite.com/localhost